# mp4 won't play on ios

Tags: ios, html, video

I'm trying to get a mp4 to play on IOS and I'm stuck.  I've added the meme types to my .htaccess 
file and they seem to be working.

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm    
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/mp4 .m4a
AddType audio/wav /wav
```

I wrote my host to see if there might be more server config required but no.  They suggested that it's the way I'm encoding the video.  I've tried it with two codecs H.264 and avc1.42E01E.  I'm using the AVS Video Editor to create the files.

http://richpoints.com/b-path/1.html

I have no way of testing but I suspect it works on Android.  How can I make this render on IOS?

Thanks
Rich

Comment: UPDATE. I read that mobile devices won't render videos larger than their screen size; no compression.  So I created a new file, this time using m4v format and I can get the file to play with a direct link.  However when I try to link to it from a video tag it doesn't render.

    <video controls autoplay>
      <source src="skunk-creek/Untitled.m4v" type='video/m4v; codecs="H.264"'>
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

I've tried it with and without the codec and both don't work.

What should I try now?